# VS2013 Microsoft.Bcl warnings when package is installed

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am getting warnings as follows;

Warning 2   Project must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl, version=1.1.9. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317570.

I have the package installed from nuget, but its version 1.0.21, anyone know how to find the version referenced and why it wasn't installed from nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Well it would've been more appropriate to list the actual package name, which is Microsoft BCL Portability Pack. Installing that solves the issue of the warnings.

Comment: Microsoft VS2019 latest edition still produces the error link above but the Microsoft error link is currently broken (try it in original post, above) :(  Same for other similar error links I tried. It forwards to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improved-package-restore.aspx and reports: 403 Forbidden, nginx

Comment: BTW The packages concerned for me were: Microsoft.Bcl.Build, Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Net.Http.  Presumably something to do with today's update of VS20019 and Microsoft.Net.Compiler and Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset nuget packages from 3.8.0 to 3.9.0