# Projects with Microsoft.Bcl installed still give warning "Project must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Our solution has 43 C# projects, targeting .Net Framework 4.0. When building the solution (in Visual Studio 2015), we are getting a lot of warnings saying "Project must install nuget package Microsoft.Bcl". When we check the NuGet packages for those projects, Microsoft.Bcl is installed.
Restore NuGet packages says "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore".

In [VS2013 Microsoft.Bcl warnings when package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380944/vs2013-microsoft-bcl-warnings-when-package-is-installed) suggested solution is to install the package Microsoft BCL Portability Pack, but I can not find a package with that name.

Why are we getting these warnings when the package is installed?

Why do we get these warnings multiple times per project?

Why do some warnings ask for Microsoft.Bcl version 1.1.8, while most ask for version 1.1.10?

Answer (score 0):

First, please uninstall the packages.
Second, reinstall them through nuget.

Please try it out.
Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately that causes a chain of dependent packages, that have to be uninstalled. All these packages are installed in some but not all projects. After writing down the list of projects for each dependent package, uninstalling and reinstalling them, a project rebuild resulted in over 400 errors, due to missing references. I checked some, and the reference seems to be there. After a revert, the build was successful. For the time being I will ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked. Make sure your packages.config has this entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```